# "Does my dividend increase over years?" or "Is my dividend increase over years?"

Tags: grammar

I was wondering, which sentence is more accurate? Or, both are acceptable?

```
Does my dividend increase over years?
```

Or

```
Is my dividend increase over years?
```

Answer (score 5):

First, "over years" sounds wrong somehow. Instead try "over time".

Either of the following are grammatical:

> Does my dividend increase over time?

or

> Will my dividend increase over time?

If you want to use "Is", the meaning of the sentence changes:

> Is my dividend increasing over time?

The first two are questions you could ask before making an investment. The third you could ask after making the investment, if you wanted to see how it's doing.